# cast on generate_series gives: ERROR: set-valued function called in context that cannot accept a set

Tags: postgresql

Somehow in postgres when I add a days-interval to a date I get a timestamp. So I would like to cast it back to a date.
I have a generate_series of so timestamps and would like to cast them to dates:

```
select *
from cast(generate_series(current_date-interval'7 days',current_date,'1 day')as date)gs(date);
```

When I do this, I get:

```
ERROR:  set-valued function called in context that cannot accept a set
```

Also when I do not use dates, but integers there is no error:

```
select * from cast(generate_series(1,15,2)as int);
```

Also the following gives no error:

```
select cast(generate_series(current_date-interval'7 days',current_date,'1 day')as date)gs(date);
```

I also have another question: the error message is talking about sets. To be honest, I only know tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`generate_series()` returns a [set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_(mathematics)) of rows which is similar to a table. And obviously you can't cast a set to a single data type. Your cast is similar to `select * from cast(some_table as date)`

You need to cast the value that is returned by the function:

```
select gs.date::date as "date"
from generate_series(current_date - interval '7 days', current_date, '1 day') gs(date)
```

Comment: Okay, but why 'select cast(generate_series(current_date-interval'7 days',current_date,'1 day')as date) works?

Comment: because in that case the set returning function (`generate_series()` ) is used as a select list expression as well and represents the single value returned by the function. In general set returning functions should not be  used in the `select` list.

Comment: Now I do not understand what you are writing. I will ask you later about this in this comments, if that is OK.

Comment: Just remember that functions like `generate_series()` should be used in the `FROM` clause.